# Display List in UiTableView under corresponding Sections in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Problem: The code mentioned below populates value for both the sections where it should populate under the relevant section headers (Sections namely: Active and  Finished)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIdentifier = "MainTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    DispatchQueue.main.async{

        let theGame = self.game[indexPath.row]
        if (theGame.status == "Finished" )
        {
            let finishedGame =  theGame
            cell.userName?.text = finishedGame.myTeamState.team.players[1].username

        }
        else{
            let otherGame =  theGame
            cell.userName?.text = otherGame.myTeamState.team.players[1].username

        }

    }
  return cell
}
```

I think, am not able to understand how to get the header section to nest values/populate List inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create two arrays from your game array:

```
var finishedArray = []
var activeArray = [] 

for item in game {
  if item.status == "Finished" {
    finishedArray.append(item)
 }else {
    activeArray.append(item)
 }
}

tableView.reloadData
```

After this, use the numberOfRowsInSection method:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
           return finishedArray.count
        }else {
           return activeArray.count
        }
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellIdentifier = "MainTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
             let theGame = self.finishedArray[indexPath.row]
             let finishedGame =  theGame
             cell.userName?.text = finishedGame.myTeamState.team.players[1].username

       }
        else{
             let theGame = self.activeArray[indexPath.row]
            let otherGame =  theGame
            cell.userName?.text = otherGame.myTeamState.team.players[1].username

        }

  return cell
}
```

You also need to add numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection methods as well.

Comment: I have added them    

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gameList.count
    }

Comment: That's not correct. You need to add the exact count of number of rows in each section. It's better to segregate the array into active and finished arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also telI, post segregating the arrays into two. how do I need to section wise add lists to Sections. 

that would be a great help.